# Can't run a .jar file that used to work just fine

Tags: java, php, shell, path

My problem is I can't run "file.jar parameters" from Windows console. I used to be able to do just that.

Now I have to use the "java -jar file.jar parameters" syntax to get it to work - otherwise I just get "'could not load main class" error. I've changed path variables, reinstalled java etc. and it only made it messier.

How do I return to the point where I can just write file.jar in the console and make it run? I HAVE to be able to do this because I call this script from PHP shell and for whatever funky reason the shell doesn't work when I call it via the "java -jar file.jar parameters" syntax - but it used to work with the "file.jar parameters" syntax.

I hate java it's a mess and i have multiple lib folders, some trash from previous installations it's a disaster and i am raging after trying to fix it for the last 6 hours... somebody please help me i am near throwing the computer through the window

Comment: It's "possible" that your PHP shell is doing a "open" which is finding the association between "java" and ".jar".  I don't know of any means to simple type "file.jar parameters" and get a jar file to execute, as a jar file, in of itself, is simply not executed from the context of the OS (only .exe, .com and .bat (a few select others) are executable..)

Comment: Which OS is that for? Ubuntu? Mac?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos *"from Windows console"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just create a .bat file with content "java -jar file.jar"
Then your PHP shell can execute the bat directly